# Solr 3.6 Suggester distributed search and no results

Tags: solr

I have an environment as follows:

"core a":
solr2.domain.com:8080/solr/core_a

"core b":
solr2.domain.com:8080/solr/core_b

Both have a /suggest request hander and a suggester search component. They have different schema.xml.

I also have a "master" solr on server solr1.domain.com:8080/solr.

Now, when I do a query to the suggester as follows I get no results:
http://solr1.domain.com:8080/solr/select?q=a&shards.qt=/suggest&shards=solr2.domain.com:8080/solr/core_a,solr2.domain.com:8080/solr/core_b

When I call suggester components directly, for example like this
shards=solr2.domain.com:8080/solr/core_a/suggest?q=a
I get results.